# on Python, I want to do this : remove or map list or for loop two lists in same time

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have 2 lists:

```
Mlist = ['alex','peter','alan','david']
Flist = ['mary','kitty','susan','amy']
```

I want to find `'peter'` then remove `'peter'` and `'kitty'` (in `Flist` with same index of `'peter'` in `Mlist`)

Comment: You know this looks a lot like homework. It is not against the rules to ask homework questions given you *first* show some effort yourself and have specific questions about why your attempt is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mlist = ['alex','peter','alan','david']
Flist = ['mary','kitty','susan','amy']
idx=Mlist.index('peter')
Mlist.remove(Mlist[idx])
Flist.remove(Flist[idx])

print (Mlist)
print (Flist)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find anything in list by value:

> listName.count('value')

To get Index of an element :

> listName.index('value')

Hope you can solve it :)